# HTML2Pdf content is overflowing out of page

Tags: php, html, css, html2pdf

I am trying to generate a PDF from an HTML File using the HTML2PDF library.

My HTML :

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top">
        <table width="968" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <strong>Invoice </strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" valign="top">
                    <span style="text-align:right;">#24638 </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <table width="968" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="50%" align="left" valign="top">
                                <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">To</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" valign="top">test user
                                            <br />
                                             Some Company22
                                            <br />
                                            My Address
                                            <br />
                                             Line 2
                                            <br />
                                            City, 487030
                                            <br />
                                            State, Country
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td width="50%" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <table width="968" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="17%" align="center" valign="top">Transaction Date</td>
                            <td width="6%" align="center" valign="top">User ID</td>
                            <td width="26%" align="center" valign="top">UserName</td>
                            <td width="9%" align="center" valign="top">Order</td>
                            <td width="21%" align="center" valign="top">Tax </td>
                            <td width="21%" align="center" valign="top">Tax Description</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">04-11-2015</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">137</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">saurabh.pande@dfordomains.com</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">24727</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Mauris placerat </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <table width="968" border="1" align="left" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="49%" align="center" valign="top">Description</td>
                            <td width="27%" align="center" valign="top">Invoice Amount</td>
                            <td width="24%" align="center" valign="top">Pending Amount</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo</td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">USD 5.98 </td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">USD 0 </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <table width="500" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="51%" align="left" valign="top">Foreign Exchange Rate when Invoice was paid (EUR To USD) </td>
                            <td width="49%" align="left" valign="top">Mauris placerat </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top">Total Amount</td>
                            <td align="left" valign="top">USD 5.98</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I use this code to gerate the PDF :

```
$pdfdata = myHtml() // returns my generated HTML
require_once(__DIR__.'path/to/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
try{
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','en');
    $html2pdf->WriteHTML($pdfdata);
    $html2pdf->Output('transaction.pdf');
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

However in the Output the table width exceeds the page width and half the content is not visible.[image]

Comment: so, what is your question? what did you try?

Comment: Set the width to 968 could be the problem here

Comment: Tried that , Does not work

Comment: Try this below link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793792/html2pdf-table-content-is-overflowing-out-of-page?rq=1
it would help you.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the `<page>` it is bordered to your pdf pages

```
<page backtop="30mm" backbottom="15mm" backleft="5mm" backright="10mm" pagegroup="new" style="font-family: freeserif;">     
    <page_header>                 
    </page_header>
    <page_footer style="text-align: center;">
    </page_footer>
</page>
```